Squash and merge vs Regular merge
If I am merging a feature branch feature into the main branch, what difference does it make (with respect to the main branch's history) whether I do a squash and merge or a simple merge?
Before merge:
main:     A---B---C
feature:      \-D---E---F

After regular merge:
main:     A---B---C-------G
feature:      \-D---E---F-/

After squash merge:
main:     A---B---C---G'
feature:      \-D---E---F

In both cases main's history contains only 4 commits. What did the squash achieve?


probably it's not related to stackoverflow question, it's more google's question, 2) after simple merge you see all branch commits + merge commit, after squash - 1 branch commit + merge commit, it's easy to see just 1 commit in history for feature, and easy to rollback it


If you look at ancestors of G, you'll see D, E, F. You cannot see them with G'. If D, E, F make sense as individual commits: do not squash ; otherwise squash. Keep in mind you can also use interactive rebase locally to squash only D and E for instance for keep F.

You are merging A -> B
In the case of normal merge this would mean that all the commits that were done for A will be transferred into B.
In the case of squash merge, all the commits of A will be squashed into a single commit and B will have no information of what commits A had, when they were committed etc. etc., but, instead, it will have a single merge commit.

In my example, after doing a normal merge main received only one new commit (the merge commit, G). Your statement: "all the commits that were done for A will be transferred into B" does not seem accurate in light of this example

@AyushGarg "Squash merging is a merge option that allows you to condense the Git history of topic branches when you complete a pull request. Instead of each commit on the topic branch being added to the history of the default branch, a squash merge adds all the file changes to a single new commit on the default branch." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging-with-squash?view=azure-devops

@AyushGarg Git Merge: "Merge integrates the entire history of one branch into another, including all the individual commits from the feature branch. It creates a new commit on the target branch, known as a “merge commit.”" https://medium.com/@shikha.ritu17/git-rebase-vs-merge-vs-squash-choosing-the-right-strategy-for-version-control-a9c9bb97040e

@AyushGarg so merge will create a merge commit into the target branch which will have the commits of the source branch in its history. Squash merge will condense all changes into a single commit. You claim that you did a normal merge but the source branch's commits are not appearing as separate commits in the revision history of the target branch. Since I have experimented with both merges and the result confirmed my statement as well as all the articles one could find, either you discovered some highly improbable git bug, or, probably, you misunderstood something.

@AyushGarg please try and reproduce the error. Let's say that you just created a repository. Let's suppose that you branch out a feature branch from master (or main, doesn't matter which name it is), create 5 commits in your new feature branch and then apply a normal merge from this feature branch into your main branch. Do you experience the behavior you claimed to see in this case? If so, what are the exact reproduction steps?
